# tcl : grep, regexp to remove string pattern from file

Tags: regex, grep, tcl

the file contain strings like following :

```
str1.str2.
str1.str2.str3.
str1.str2.str3.1.
str1.str2.str3.1.p
```

when parse the file line by line if the `$str = "str1.str2."` then remove all string except  `str1.str2.str3.`
for that I use this :

```
exec sh -c "grep $str file |grep -v $str[A-Za-z_0-9]\+\.[A-Za-z_0-9] |grep -v ^$str.$ > dest_file"
```

but this one I doesn't work "invalid command [A-Za-z_0-9]  !!

what 's wrong with this tcl command

Comment: Recall that Tcl's command substitution syntax is `[command]` with square brackets. Since the grep pipeline is in a double quoted string, Tcl will attempt to perform command and variable substitution on the string. You'll need to escape the `[` -- see http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm

Comment: You also have the same issues as with your other question.  Any backslash that you want to pass on to the shell has to be doubled.  The `$` anchor passed to grep should be protected from both tcl and from the shell.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood it well, having a file like this in input:

```
$ cat file
blah
str1.str2.
str1.str2.str3.
str1.str2.str3.1.
str1.str2.str3.1.p
blah
```

You want in output the single line containing `str1.str2.str3.`. If this is the case you can replace your multiple, piped, grep commands with a single one:

```
$ grep -E ${str}[^.]+.\$ file
str1.str2.str3.
```

As reported in the comments here above you will have to "protect" backslashes from tcl substitution by doubling them.